# What part number is this 20-pin connector?

Tags: connector, identification

Pin pitch is 1mm, row spacing 2.5mm. DigiKey filter search turns up empty. Two of these are used on a MiTAC motherboard, one for custom MiAPI and one as (probably) for a parallel port. Nothing helpful is silk-screened on the motherboard around this connector.

[image: connector]

Comment: You sure about that row spacing? Looks an awful lot like this [Molex Pico-Clasp](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/5011902027/WM12955CT-ND/5973716) part.

Comment: Not to 0.1mm precision, I don't have a slide gauge handy. That's probably it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be Molex Part [5011902027](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/5011902027/WM12955CT-ND/5973716) which is a 1mm pitch and what I suspect is a 2.66mm row spacing.
[image]